# Ansible jinja 2 template value should not changed

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I have written jinja2 template in ansible. What i am trying to achieve is that if the service_name is not mentioned and if service_name already exists on the remote machine, ansible should not change the service_name with default name mentioned in the template. However, when the service_name is not defined,  ansible replaces service name with "abc" on remote machine even service_name exists. Any help would be appreciated.

```
active={{ active_status}} 
instrument={{ instrument_status }} 
{% if service_name is defined %} 
service_name={{ service_name }} 
{% else %} 
service_name=abc 
{% endif %}
```

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible only with copying a template. What you  are currently getting is the expected result. You need more logic around it: read the file if it exists, see if there is service name already defined, if there is a service name already defined in the file and `service_name` is currently unset, set `service_name` with value, then copy your template (which will then not change if all other values are identical).

Comment: Could you please paste the whole snippet of the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Following my above comment, here is a possible example implementation to meet your requirements. `test_template.j2` is the exact copy of your current template. You can pass the service name as an extra variable to test (`-e service_name=my_service`)

Basically, if `service_name` is not defined, we:

- Check if the remote file already exists and [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) its content into a var
- Look for the relevant line in the file. Note: the `regex_replace('None', '')` is here to make sure we get an empty string if previous search/matches did not return anything.
- Set the service name only if something relevant was found in the prior tasks

Once this check/setting is done correctly, you simply have to copy your template, what ever the case is.

```
---
- name: Conditional writing of template
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_dest: /tmp/test_file.txt
    active_status: some active value
    instrument_status: some instrument value

  tasks:

    - name: Try to read service name from existing file when it is not defined
      when: service_name is not defined
      block:
        - name: Check if file exists
          stat:
            path: "{{ my_dest }}"
          register: my_file

        - name: Try to read target file if exists
          slurp:
            src: "{{ my_dest }}"
          when: my_file.stat.exists
          register: my_file_slurp

        - name: Look for service name if there
          set_fact:
            looked_service: >-
              {{
                my_file_slurp.content
                | b64decode
                | regex_search('^service_name=.*$', multiline=true)
                | regex_replace('^service_name=(.*)$', '\1')
                | regex_replace('None', '')
              }}
          when: my_file.stat.exists

        - name: Update service name if found
          set_fact:
            service_name: "{{ looked_service }}"
          when: looked_service | default('') | length > 0


    - name: Copy template file to destination
      template:
        src: test_template.j2
        dest: "{{ my_dest }}"
```